# SOLVED - IdP Shibboleth Injected service was null or not an AttributeResolver

Tags: tomcat, ldap, shibboleth, idp

I have installed a Shibboleth IdPv3.3.2 on a CentOS 7 and when I try to access him through `https://localhost/idp/` (or `https://localhost/idp/status/`) shows nothing (and sometimes a 503 Error). I've opened ports on firewall and nothing happened. The apache works fine on status screen. The tomcat apparently is working too (said the service status).

Looking through tomcat's log I found this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shibboleth.metrics.RegisterMetricSets$child#0' defined in file [/opt/shibboleth-idp/system/conf/../../conf/admin/metrics.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'shibboleth.metrics.AttributeResolverGaugeSet' while setting bean property 'arguments' with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shibboleth.metrics.AttributeResolverGaugeSet' defined in file [/opt/shibboleth-idp/system/conf/general-admin-system.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Injected service was null or not an AttributeResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shibboleth.metrics.AttributeResolverGaugeSet' defined in file [/opt/shibboleth-idp/system/conf/general-admin-system.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Injected service was null or not an AttributeResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Injected service was null or not an AttributeResolver
    at net.shibboleth.idp.attribute.resolver.impl.AttributeResolverServiceGaugeSet.doInitialize(AttributeResolverServiceGaugeSet.java:104)
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.AbstractInitializableComponent.initialize(AbstractInitializableComponent.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 37 more
```

That is a lot of exceptions and I found nothing to explain on others places.

Would somebody help me?

### [EDIT]

I've solve it by setting SELinux to permissive mode

Comment: I have the same error, I'm working on this:
https://github.com/peppelinux/Ansible-Shibboleth-IDP-SP-Debian9

If something changes I'll tell you :)

Comment: Apparently was something to do with SELinux. You must configure SELinux to give some access to tomcat...or just run
     setenforce 0
on terminal. I don't know if this will work on Debian cause, as said before, I'm running it on CentOS 7...try and tell

Comment: I solved this, Check underling datasource connection and attribute-resolver.xml syntax. Are you migrating from idpv3.2.1 to idp3.3.2?